# leaflet.js marker-icon-2x and marker-shadow.png not loading

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dc.leaflet.js

is it possible to use a custom icon on my Leaflet map?
I tried to do something like :

```
   function onLocationFound(e) {
        var radius = e.accuracy / 2;

        var customIcon = L.icon({
          iconUrl: 'images/marker_icon_2x.png',
          shadowUrl: 'images/marker_shadow.png'
        });    
        L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();

        L.circle(e.latlng, radius).addTo(map);
    }
```

but I did not work, does anyone know the best way to do it?
the icon appears with the wrong size and also in another position

Comment: update  I added this as well :
```L.marker(e.latlng, {icon: customIcon}).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup("You are within " + radius + " meters from this point").openPopup();```
Ref: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: What do you mean with "wrong size"? You specified the retina marker URL, it's twice as big. You need to specify `iconAnchor` and other properties to correct the position ([see here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/)), please let us know if you need help with that

Comment: It would be helpful in debugging if you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your issue.